# Unable to send Class Object on Parse Cloud for Android app

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using Parse as a backend for my android application and I'm new to Parse API.I am following their Quick Start tutorial but just not able to send and save object on Cloud.Kindly help me in solving this problem.

Thank you.

Here's snippet from my code :

```
Parse.initialize(this,"App id","Client key");


        ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
        ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();

        // If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this line.
        defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);

        ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

        ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
        testObject.put("foo", "bar");
        testObject.saveInBackground();
```

Comment: Do you have a class called TestObject on parse?

Comment: Nop i dont have but doccumentation says It automatically creates one if it is not on cloud

Comment: As you mentioned the broken pipe error. Its normally caused when the connection on the client side is closed. Also, check if a class was created or not, maybe the column doesn't exist and is causing the error.

Comment: Doccumentationn says - You didn't have to configure or set up a new Class before running this code. Your Parse app lazily creates this Class for you when it first encounters it.

Comment: @Aashir :Even i check  by creating class and corresponding column on cloud

Comment: did you give internet permissions in manifest?

Comment: Yes.I have already given.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you may have forgot to put this permissions in the manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```